# adding mutiple dropdown button HTML CSS javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create multiple dropdowns with text inside each of them. The problem here is i am only able to create 1 dropdown and if try to create another the code does not work anymore. the following is the code for 1 dropdown. Can any kind soul advice on how to create another dropdown under the first dropdown? thanks in advance :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: [W3Schools](https://w3schools.com)

Comment: Please use proper attribution when copying code from somewhere else.

Comment: This was taken from w3schools :)

Comment: I know, but the attribution must be made in the question itself. I will edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function targets the dropdown menu by ID. When you make another copy of your dropdown menu, you run into a duplicate id conflict. Remove the id; you actually don't need it. It is there to simplify the example. Modify your code like this:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(e) {
  e.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

As I stated earlier, this example has been simplified a lot for beginners, to the extent that it has so many unnecessary parts. For example, you can replace

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

by

```
for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].classList.remove(show);
}
```

and the code should still work.